# Displaying a notification on page after redirect

Tags: php

I have a page with a form on it.

If the forms is submitted I redirect to that page again.

On the page I want to display a notification that the data is saved.

I'm looking for a clean way to know that I have to display the notification.

First I thought of adding something to the url:

```
/page?notify=1
```

But I don't like to change the URL.

Then I thought of setting a session before the redirect.

And on the page I check if the session is set, display the notification if it is and unset it.

Would that be an acceptable way of doing it or is there perhaps a better / cleaner way?

Comment: A session is a fine & almost default way to do it.

Comment: @Wrikken: and what would be the default way to do it? :)

Comment: Like you say: set a var in a session, on display, check if it's set, display & unset. You could even make it generic with a standard box shown on any page & a `notices` array in the session.

Comment: @Wrikken: k. you said almost default way so I thought there was a better way :)

Comment: Afaik there is no other truly default way, with 'almost default' I meant this solution was most common, but there are other less used ones which may have an advantage in specific circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally think the `?notify=` is perfectly acceptable. You're not going to have spiders crawling that page and since it's only a confirmation notification you don't need to worry about the page being indexed. Don't be afraid of query strings when you're out of the SEO realm - just look at Amazon.com :)

Ultimately it comes down to code re-usability and effort of implementation.

Comment: I know I don't have to worry about SEO. I just hate the look of query strings :D But that can be just me being obsessive :P

Comment: The problem is all the users that contact you in panic after some clown has fed them a link to `/page?notify=1`, where they see they have submitted something and demand it being reversed :)

Comment: @PeeHaa: haha, I'm a huge fan of programmers who are obsessive, since it shows a lot of dedication to their art.  I use to avoid query strings as well, but I've made my peace with them.  They're actually preferable over session for data that is not secured.  Your solution with ?notify= is solid

Comment: On the flip-side, maybe that's what the user wants to show the other user. With a session, that's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

A session is fine. A cookie that you delete immediately after would be even cleaner. Since a session id is usually a larger cookie than this anyways, and takes storage on your server.

```
setcookie('notify',1,time()+60); // Expire in one minute. Redirect should be faster.
```

Then on your page they are being redirected to:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['notify']) && $_COOKIE['notify'] == 1){
    // Notification output
    setcookie('notify', '', time()-1);
}
```

**Another Option** you have is to is redirect the user to /page/notify and use your .htaccess with Rewrite Mod to rewrite that as /page?notify.

Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/notify/?$ $1?notify=1
```

Comment: hmmmmm cookie (Homer Simpson style). Using a cookie hey. Interesting. Why would it be cleaner?

Comment: Ahum, we're talking a few bytes storage, a key & and integer? But I take your point that if you don't already have a session, it has some overhead. On the other hand, the cookie solution may be inconvenient with possible headers already been sent.

Comment: I updated my post. Unless you're already using sessions, making a new session just for this purpose just uses a cookie anyways. All a session is is a cookie stored on the clients computer with an id telling your server where to look for the session file, which is actually stored on your server. That id is usually fairly long. Something like PHPSESSID=08d9600c10d135bc38e098ec6da44575 for example, which is a bigger than notify=1

Comment: @Wrikken. I know, I said in my post a session is fine too. I do think this is a little bit cleaner though.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a form, maybe you also have a submit button.  You can check if the form is submitted like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['go'])) {
        // The form has been submitted.
        echo("Saved!");
    }
?>
<form method = 'post' action = ''>
    <input type = 'submit' id = 'go' name = 'go' value = 'Submit'/>
</form>
```

**EDIT**

Since that won't work.. I generally keep a session variable as an array (I call it 'errors', but I use it for just general output).  It's an array because it can hold multiple messages, and then on every single page display I dump whatever is in that array whererever I want to display those messages.  This has worked for me across multiple projects, and seems to me to be a pretty good way of storing messages to be sent to the user

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['errors'] = array();

...

array_push($_SESSION['errors'], "<span style = 'color:green;'>Success!</span>");
header("Location: somepage.php");
```

And then display...

```
if(isset($_SESSION['errors']) && count($_SESSION['errors']) > 0) {
    foreach($_SESSION['errors'] as $k => $v)
        echo($v . "<br/>");
    unset($_SESSION['errors']);
}
```

Comment: No can't do. After (successful) submission of the form I do a redirect. (/offtopic which everyone should do ;) )

Comment: OK, and now for _after_ a _redirect_. Remember: the `$_POST` array is then empty.

Comment: @PeeHaa: /offtopic: yup, I agree, no idiotic 'post again?' nonsense & duplicates...

Comment: "If the forms is submitted I redirect to that page again." - Sorry, I thought that meant you were posting the form to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden field in your form like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" />
```

Then when the page is reloaded you can do this:

```
if($_POST['action'] == "submit"){
  // show that data was saved
}
```

I mean ideally you'll want to make sure the data was actually saved but Im not getting much into your implementation.

Comment: Although I didn't downvote. My question states that I'm doing a redirect. So there will be no `$_POST['action']`. I guess that's what the downvote is for.

Comment: Sorry, I guess people had trouble understanding "If the forms is submitted a redirect to that page again."

Comment: No need to apologize. Just blame me and I'll blame my keyboard ;) --> Fixed

Answer (score 0):

first_page.php

```
$_SESSION['notify'] = 9;
```

second_page.php

```
if($_SESSION['notify'] > 0){
     notify(9);
     $_SESSION['notify'] = 0;
}
```